# Get document with the minimum value for a field for each group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with two documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5784def78c669ee061519aaf"),
    "name" : "nithin",
    "sal" : 2000.0,
    "age" : 20.0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5784def78c669ee061519ab0"),
    "name" : "nithin",
    "sal" : 20.0,
    "age" : 2000.0
}
```

I want to find the minimum sal for a given name and the **corresponding** age

In this case minimum sal would be 20 and the **corresponding** age would be 2000

Ran my query as follows :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
"$group":{"_id":"$name" ,"minSalary" :{"$min":"$sal"} , "ages":{"$addToSet":{"ageval":"$age","salval":"$sal"}}}}
,{"$project": {
         "_id":0,
          "sal":"$minSalary",
         "ages":  "$ages"
      }
  },
  {
   "$unwind":"$ages"   
   }
   ,
   {
    **"$match":{ "ages.salval":**20** }**  
    }
]
)
```

But the problem is i want the $match to apply directly on the minSalary and not harcode the filter value to 20 . Please help

Answer (score 5):

Simply [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your documents by "name" and "sal" in ascending order, then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by "name" and return the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first) document using the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) system variable.

```
db.test.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$sort": { "name": 1, "sal": 1 } }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$name", 
            "matched_doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } 
        }} 
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your question to be somewhat unclear, but here are attempts for two scenarios.

1. Grouping age and name together, then get the min salary. Returns minimum salaries of people of the same name and age group

`db.getCollection('sal').aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : { 
                age : "$age", 
                name : "$name"
            }, 
            minSal : {
                $min : "$sal"
            }
        }
    }
])`

2. Grouping by age group only, getting min salary for each age group

`db.getCollection('sal').aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$age", minSal : { $min : "$sal"}
        }
    }
])`